# simple newbie join

Tags: sql

I am not sure here on the syntax. I want to join file a and file b
where a.ent = b.ent and a.suf - b.suf i want one col from file b
which is grc# even if blank.

```
Select * from mylib.filea a left join
hislib.fileb b
where a.ent = b.ent
and a.suf = b.suf
```

Comment: `WHERE` should be `ON` for a join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `ON` instead of `WHERE` when it comes to join statements.

```
SELECT * from mylib.filea a
LEFT JOIN hislib.fileb b
ON a.ent = b.ent AND a.suf = b.suf
```

You would use `WHERE` like this

```
SELECT * from mylib.filea a
LEFT JOIN hislib.fileb b
ON a.ent = b.ent AND a.suf = b.suf
WHERE a.ent = 'some value'
```

You can find out more about JOIN syntax on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `where` with `on`.

```
Select * from mylib.filea a left join
hislib.fileb b
on a.ent = b.ent
and a.suf = b.suf
```